# PLSQL that creates a Job and a Schedule

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle DB how do I extract the PLSQL that creates a Job and a Schedule from existing objects?

I am using SQL Developer but any other method is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the DDL statement for a job, you can use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` with the `PROCOBJ` object type:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ', job_name) 
from user_scheduler_jobs;
```

**UPDATE**

The same approach works for schedules:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ', schedule_name) 
from user_scheduler_schedules;
```